# Can a stolen chip & pin card be used to withdraw cash from an ATM without knowing the actual pin?

Tags: credit-card

My chip and pin Visa debit card was stolen from a gym locker and successfully used to withdraw money from an ATM in 2017 in London, England. The PIN was not recorded anywhere and yet the card was used and the bank has refused a refund because the PIN must have been known to the thief.
It is truly perplexing and I would appreciate any comments on how this may have been done?

Comment: Was your PIN something that's easy to guess? Birth year, 1234, etc.

Comment: Was PIN set by you before first use or did it come up with a card? Have you ever changed PIN of that card?